# Canvas border radius using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to set border radius for canvas following is my code a set Height is applying perfectly also set Width applying perfectly just having the issue with border radius just tell how to set border radius of canvas using following code.

```
   canvas.setHeight(314);
   canvas.setWidth(629);
   canvas.setBorderRadius(314.5/157.25);
```

Comment: I'd recommend making an request on the repo for this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `setBorderRadius` method in Fabric.

You can always change border-radius of canvas element via CSS (in supporting browsers).